# Applescript, read lines as variables

Tags: text, applescript

I want Applescript to set variables from a txt file, read line by line or character by character. Maybe like the php function: get_file_contents. Is there anything similar or could you please provide me the way?

I know how to set the file path. It's like

```
    set myfile to "/Users/Username/Desktop/test.txt"
    set theText to read myfile
```

In the txt file, it's just one integer in one line, like

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

If I use

```
    set theTextList to paragraphs of theText
```

the result will have quotation marks "".

I just want to set these integer numbers to a variable. So that later I could use, like

```
   set variable to 5  --here I would like to replace the real number 5 to the number I read from the txt file(just one line)

   start slideshow
   show slide variable
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not really sure this should have a php tag associated with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the lines of the file are delimited by return characters, something like this should work:

```
set allRecords to read myfile using delimiter return
repeat with aRecord in allRecords
    if length of aRecord is greater than 0 then
        set variable to aRecord
        log "variable: " & variable
    end if
end repeat
```

You can change the delimiting character in the first line of the code if in your file is something different than return.

Comment: Of course: 
set variable to first item of (read myfile using delimiter return)
log "variable: " & variable

Comment: thanks, it works...I have sth wrong with the txt file. it cannot be delimited by return characters...but i changed it to a comma.

Comment: Maybe you had linefeed instead of return as line delimiter. In that case you could replace return with linefeed in the script above.